# How to connect remote windows machine from linux terminal?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, python, ssh-tunnel

I want to execute windows command on remote windows machine from linux terminal.

Comment: you can use [winexe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinExe)

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend PsExec, its made by Mark Russinovich, so you know it works..

> Utilities like Telnet and remote control programs like Symantec's PC
>   Anywhere let you execute programs on remote systems, but they can be a
>   pain to set up and require that you install client software on the
>   remote systems that you wish to access. PsExec is a light-weight
>   telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems,
>   complete with full interactivity for console applications, without
>   having to manually install client software. PsExec's most powerful
>   uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems
>   and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the
>   ability to show information about remote systems.

Just because M$ annexed him.. doesn't *sniff* make him a sell-out..

Download: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553

Detail by Mark: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/psexec

Matter of fact, anyone who has to use a MS system should have a copy of the Sysinternals Suite on hand: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default

Comment: Sorry, just deleted & undeleted, had to test that it ran under Wine as you specified linux. It does!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to install cygwin on the Windows machine and install ssh server.
There is a lot of howto's for example [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used rdesktop http://www.rdesktop.org/ to RDP to Windows systems from a Linux system.  It has worked very well for me.

Sorry, you are looking for winexe.

Winexe remotely executes commands on Windows NT/2000/XP/2003 systems from GNU/Linux (and possibly also from other Unices capable of building the Samba 4 software package).